# composer facebook/graph-sdk requires php-http/client-implementation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, composer-php

I am on localhost (xamp) and trying with composer to include facebook graph-sdk according to [Facebook SDK for PHP](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk?fbclid=IwAR0LS8FtL-xNaXgKzwR_DB9U11req9jL47u-8EMomb01bJ9gaubhOhHtLms). After using `composer require facebook/graph-sdk` I got following error:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for facebook/graph-sdk ^6.0@dev -> satisfiable by facebook/graph-sdk[6.x-dev].
    - facebook/graph-sdk 6.x-dev requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.
```

Ok so I used google and found out that something like 'virtual package' is needed to implement. Supposedly it is commonnly `php-http/guzzle6-adapter` or `php-http/curl-client`. Since [Facebook SDK for PHP](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk?fbclid=IwAR0LS8FtL-xNaXgKzwR_DB9U11req9jL47u-8EMomb01bJ9gaubhOhHtLms) says: "There are issues when using the Facebook SDK together with Guzzle 6.x." I chose Curle client.

```
composer require php-http/httplug-bundle php-http/curl-client
```

It caused that my another attempt to install Facebook SDK ended with more errors.

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for facebook/graph-sdk ^6.0@dev -> satisfiable by facebook/graph-sdk[6.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: remove php-http/httplug 2.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install php-http/httplug 2.0.x-dev
```

So I removed it. `composer remove php-http/httplug 2.0.x-dev` but there is no difference from previous attempt.

I am so confused. How can I install facebook graph sdk??

EDIT:

composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "tomas/tmvdev",
    "description": "wordpress theme",
    "keywords": ["WordPress", "Theme"],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/vavra7/tmvdev",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GNU",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Tomáš Vavřinka",
            "email": "email@tomasvavrinka.cz",
            "homepage": "http://tomasvavrinka.cz"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php-http/curl-client": "^2.0@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Inc\\": "./inc"}
    }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to say what is happening without access to your `composer.json`.

Comment: @rob006 Question edited.

Comment: Did you tried to remove `"php-http/curl-client": "^2.0@dev"` from `require` section and then call `composer require php-http/httplug-bundle php-http/curl-client`?

Comment: @rob006 Yes and it was also my initial state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was statement in composer.json file: `"minimum-stability": "dev"`. Composer tried to download version `facebook/graph-sdk ^6.0@dev` which is not stable version.